# Fill values ​in rows with criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to fill in the values of the lines with the value 1 from the value 1.

For examplle, gostaria de transformar:

[image]

To get:

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cummax` on the rows by specifying the `MARGIN = 1` in `apply`.  When we do the row wise, the output generated is transposed as described in `?apply`

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1. If n equals 1, apply returns a vector if MARGIN has length 1 and an array of dimension dim(X)[MARGIN] otherwise. If n is 0, the result has length 0 but not necessarily the ‘correct’ dimension.

here

so do a `t` on the output to get the original structure

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, cummax))
```

---

Or another option is `rowCummaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowCummaxs(as.matrix(df1))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, could you explain the application of `t ()`?

Comment: @VeltonSousa with `MARGIN = 1`, it returns a transposed output, so we do the `t` to reverse it